# ssh connection refused when deploying meteor app from nitrous.io to Linode server using meteor up

Tags: ssh, meteor, nitrousio, linode, meteor-up

See https://github.com/arunoda/meteor-up/issues/171

I am trying to deploy my meteor app from my nitrous box to a remote server in Linode.

I follow the instruction in meteor up and got

```
Invalid mup.json file: Server username does not exit
```

mup.json

```
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "123.456.78.90",
     // "username": "root",
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      "pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
      "sshOptions": { "Port": 1024 }
    }
  ]
```

So I uncomment the username: "roote line in mup.json and I did mup logs -n 300 and got the following error:

```
[123.456.78.90] ssh: connect to host 123.456.78.90 port 1024: Connection refused
```

I suspect I may did something wrong in setting up the SSH key. I can access my remote server without password after setting up my ssh key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.

The content of the authorized_keys looks like this:

```
ssh-rsa XXXXXXXXXX..XXXX== root@apne1.nitrousbox.com
```

Do you guys have any ideas of what went wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by uncommenting the username and changing the port to 22:

```
  // Server authentication info
  "servers": [
    {
      "host": "123.456.78.90",
      "username": "root",
      // or pem file (ssh based authentication)
      "pem": "~/.ssh/id_rsa",
      "sshOptions": { "Port": 22 }
    }
  ]
```